# Server dont load data

Tags: node.js, proxy

> Request failed with status code 500
>
> /src/actions/productActions.js   Line 125:13:  'data' is assigned a
> value but never used  no-unused-vars
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning. To ignore,
> add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
>
> Proxy error: Could not proxy request
> /api/products?pageNumber=&seller=&name=&category=&min=0&max=0&rating=0&order=
> from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000. See
> https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
> more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: Can you repost or edit your question and follow the guide presented to you when first post a question? We don't know what causes the error without seeing some relevant code; you'll have better responses from people for your problem.

Comment: I do not know how to solve the problem, but Tayyab apparently trying to run this code:
https://github.com/basir/amazona